# How do I count the occurrences of a specific pattern in a column - SAS?

Tags: count, sas

I have a dataset similar to what I have included below:

```
 Hour     Value
  1         0
  2         14
  3         50
  4         110
  5         0
  6         23 
  7         35
  8         72
  9         99
  10        133
  11        187
  12         0 
  13         70
  14         100
  15         0
  16         63
  17         0
```

I want to return output that includes the number of times that the Value increases from 0 to 100 without any zeros in between.  So in this example, I would want to return '3'.  Note, hours 15,16, and 17 would not be counted as the value never reaches 100 before returning to zero.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Presume `value` always resets to `0` and otherwise always increases.

You will need

- **flag** variable to track if `value` reaches or exceeds threshold `100`

  - resets with `value`
- **count** variable to maintain number of *thresholds reached*

The **flag** and **count** should be `retain`ed so they are not reset to missing at the top of the implicit loop.

Example:

```
data have; input 
Hour     Value; datalines;
  1         0
  2         14
  3         50
  4         110
  5         0
  6         23 
  7         35
  8         72
  9         99
  10        133
  11        187
  12         0 
  13         70
  14         100
  15         0
  16         63
  17         0
;

data want;
  set have;

  retain flagged;        * explicitly specify that flag is to be retained;

  if value = 0 then flagged = 0;

  if not flagged and value >= 100 then do;
    flagged = 1;
    count + 1;            * sum statement, count implicitly retained;
  end;
run;
```

[image]